# Updating div elements in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to write an AJAX-type form with Twitter Bootstrap, but the updated div element disappears.  Can I fix that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"></head>
  <script>
  function wordCloud(){document.getElementById("cloud").innerHTML = "WordCloud";}
  </script>
  <body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <div id="cloud"></div>
  <form onsubmit="wordCloud()">
  <fieldset>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
  </form></body>
</html>
```

Comment: i suspect that you are not preventing default form action so one it submit page will reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change as follows.

```
function wordCloud(){document.getElementById("cloud").innerHTML = "WordCloud";}
```

replace

```
function wordCloud(){document.getElementById("cloud").innerHTML = "WordCloud"; return false; }
```

and

```
<form onsubmit="wordCloud()">
```

replace

```
<form onsubmit="return wordCloud()">
```